# Conditional field validation based on boolean prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I want the `favoriteAlcohol` field to be validated/required only if `props.isAdult` passed to the component is `true`.

```
Yup.object().shape({
  favoriteAlcohol: Yup.string().when(props.isAdult, {
    is: true,
    then: Yup.string().required(),
  }),
  name: Yup.string().required('Nazwa jest wymagana'),
})
```

How can I do that?

Above solution does not work, because `when` takes form's "keys" as a first argument, and I passed prop.

One working solution would be to map `prop.isAdult` to `isAdult` form value field, and then I could pass `'isAdult'` as a first argument to the `when()` function. Not the best solution, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const favoriteAlcohol = props.isAdult ? {favoriteAlcohol: Yup.string().required()} : {}

Yup.object().shape({
  ...favoriteAlcohol,
  name: Yup.string().required('Nazwa jest wymagana'),
})
```

If props.isAdult = true then, it will make

```
Yup.object().shape({
  favoriteAlcohol: Yup.string().required(),
  name: Yup.string().required('Nazwa jest wymagana'),
})
```

Otherwise, it will make

```
Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required('Nazwa jest wymagana'),
})
```

Comment: That code is useful, but your answer would be better if you could add a description on how this code fragment addresses the problem