# yup validation in react for skipping one schema

Tags: reactjs, yup

I have below schema for validation

```
const form = ({flag}) => {
  validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  flag: Yup.boolean(),
  email: Yup
    .string()
    .email()
    .when(flag, {
      is: true,
      then: Yup.string().required('Email is required'),
    }),
  firstName: Yup.string().required('FirstName is required'),
  lastName: Yup.string().required('LastName is required')
--
--
```

I'm getting a boolean value in flag, I would like to do email validation based on this flag value. If flag is true I need to do email validation, in case of false I don't need. Is it possible? I'm new to react please help me.

This line is working, but I would like to do validation based on this boolean value.

```
 email: Yup.string().email('Email must be a valid email address').required('Email is required'),
```

Below is the form snippet, Based on flag I need to show email in the form.

```
{flag && (
          <FormControl>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-email-input"
              {...register('email')}
              label="Email"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              autoComplete="email"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              helperText={isDirty && errors?.email?.message}
              error={!!errors?.email}
            />
          </FormControl>
        )}
          <FormControl>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-firstName-input"
              label="FirstName"
              type="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              autoComplete="firstName"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              {...register('firstName')}
              helperText={isDirty && errors?.firstName?.message}
              error={!!errors?.firstName}
            />
          </FormControl>
```

Comment: You are doing it right, just write `flag` as string in `.when` like this: `.when('flag', {` and write your email validation line `Yup.string().email('Email must be a valid email address').required('Email is required'),` in `then:`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537569/conditional-field-validation-based-on-boolean-prop this post helped me.

Comment: Did in different way and its working now.  thank you @Usama

Comment: no problem at all

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [test function](https://github.com/jquense/yup#validation-tests) to run a validation test at the input level, but sounds like you have it working.